# MYSQL install date using query

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL database and i want to get the install date using query, like in oracle database i can do: `SELECT CREATED FROM v$DATABASE`

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be exact if you have dropped all the tables and created them again... but then again that is when that database was re-created last...

```
SELECT MIN(CREATE_TIME) 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = DATABASE()
```